# .contains not working when reading from a text file?

Tags: java

Recently started Java and have been trying to make a database sorts of program which reads from a preset text file, the user can either search for a definition using the term or keywords/terms within the definition itself. The searching by term works fine but the key term always outputs not found.

```
  FileReader fr = new FileReader("text.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  boolean found = false;
  String line = br.readLine(); // first line so the term itself
  String lineTwo = br.readLine(); // second line which is the definition

    do {
     if (lineTwo.toLowerCase().contains(keyterm.toLowerCase())) {
        found = true;
        System.out.println("Found "+keyterm);          
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println(lineTwo);

     }
    } while ((br.readLine()!=null)&(!found));
  if (!found){System.out.println("Not Found");} br.close(); fr.close();
```

This is my method used to check for the key term which works partially, it seems to be able to find the first two lines. Which causes it to output the definition of the first term if the key term is there however it doesn't work for any of the other terms.

*edit*

The text file it reads from looks something like this:

term
definition
       term
definition

Each have their own line.

*Edit 2*

Thanks to @Matthew Kerian it now checks through the whole file, changing the end of the do while loop to

```
 while (((lineTwo = br.readLine())!=null)&(!found));
```

It now finds the actual definition but is now outputting the wrong term with it.

*Edit 3* The key term is defined by the users input

*Edit 4* If it wasn't clear the output in the end I am looking for is either the definition of the term/key term if it is in the txt file or just not found if its not found.

*Edit 5* Tried to look at what it was outputting and noticed it was outputting array (the first term in the text file) after every "lineTwo" it seems as though line is not updating.

*Final Edit* Managed to crudely solve the problem by making another text file with it flipped in the way it goes term definition it now goes definition term, lets me call upon the next line once the definition is found so it reads properly.

Comment: What are the first and second lines?

Comment: sure it works from Strings read from a file. have you debugged your code?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting additional information as comments...

Comment: Aright apologies.

Comment: What is the value of `keyterm`? What output are you expecting?

Comment: The user inputs key term so its different every time, and I've just edited it to explain it better. Once again apologies for making it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineTwo` is not begin refreshed with new data. Something like this would work better:

```
do {
 if (lineTwo.toLowerCase().contains(keyterm.toLowerCase())) {
    found = true;
    System.out.println("Found "+keyterm);          
    System.out.println(line);
    System.out.println(lineTwo);

 }
} while (((lineTwo = br.readLine())!=null)&(!found));
```

We're still checking for EOF by checking nullness, but by setting it equal to line two we're constantly refreshing our buffer.

Comment: Thanks checks the whole file but still not fully working, check edits.

Comment: @Rhys ensure that the keyterm is correctly defined. Potentially condier debugging or printing out what terms it's going through to see the issue

Comment: The key term is defined by the users input so that shouldn't be the problem?

Comment: Step through it and see what the strings are, at this point there's nothing obviously wrong so you just have to see what you overlooked

Comment: It seems like the actual line variable is not updating and stayin as "array"